# jQuery live filtering list parent and children

Tags: javascript, jquery, filtering

I'm stuck on this one; I have an input field and want to filter the results. the following function I am using at the moment;

```js
$('input[type="text"]').keyup(function() {
  var that = this,
    $allListElements = $('ul.bare-list > li');

  var $matchingListElements = $allListElements.filter(function(i, li) {
    var listItemText = $(li).text().toUpperCase(),
      searchText = that.value.toUpperCase();
    return ~listItemText.indexOf(searchText);
  });

  $allListElements.hide();
  $matchingListElements.show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="brand-container">
  <dl class="brands-letter letter-a" data-letter="letter-a">
    <dt>A</dt>
    <dd>
      <ul class="bare-list">
        <li class="brand-item">item 1</li>
        <li class="brand-item">item 2</li>
        <li class="brand-item">item 3</li>
      </ul>
    </dd>
  </dl>
  <dl class="brands-letter letter-b" data-letter="letter-b">
    <dt>B</dt>
    <dd>
      <ul class="bare-list">
        <li class="brand-item">item 1</li>
        <li class="brand-item">item 2</li>
        <li class="brand-item">item 3</li>
      </ul>
    </dd>
  </dl>
</div>
```

I want to do the following; when filtering based on the value of the `<input>` field, I want to check if all children are being set to `'display: none'`. If so, then I want to hide the parent `.brands-letter`.

Any tips on how I can handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need two more lines:

```
$allListElements.parents('.brands-letter').hide();
$matchingListElements.parents('.brands-letter').show();
```

`parents()` method will find matching parent(s) of hidden or shown elements.

Demo:

```js
$('input[type="text"]').keyup(function() {
  var that = this,
    $allListElements = $('ul.bare-list > li');

  var $matchingListElements = $allListElements.filter(function(i, li) {
    var listItemText = $(li).text().toUpperCase(),
      searchText = that.value.toUpperCase();
      
    return ~listItemText.indexOf(searchText);
  });

$allListElements.hide();
$matchingListElements.show();
//add this
$allListElements.parents('.brands-letter').hide();
$matchingListElements.parents('.brands-letter').show();


  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="brand-container">
  <dl class="brands-letter letter-a" data-letter="letter-a">
    <dt>A</dt>
    <dd>
      <ul class="bare-list">
        <li class="brand-item">item 0</li>
        <li class="brand-item">item 2</li>
        <li class="brand-item">item 3</li>
      </ul>
    </dd>
  </dl>
  <dl class="brands-letter letter-b" data-letter="letter-b">
    <dt>B</dt>
    <dd>
      <ul class="bare-list">
        <li class="brand-item">item 1</li>
        <li class="brand-item">item 2</li>
        <li class="brand-item">item 4</li>
      </ul>
    </dd>
  </dl>
</div>

<input type="text">
```

Answer (score 0):

Here 1st explictly hide one d1(class letter-a) child element(class brand-item) using JQ.

```
// here expilicitly hide all letter-a list item
const $brandItems = $('.letter-a').find('.brand-item');
$($brandItems[0]).hide();
$($brandItems[1]).hide();
$($brandItems[2]).hide();
```

Here check for each bare-list child element for display none and If all child has display none then hide parent of parent of bare-list class.

```
// Below code fulfil your requirement
const $bareLists = $('.bare-list');
$bareLists.each( (i, bareList) => {
    let hideFlag = true;
    const $brandItems = $(bareList).children();
    $brandItems.each( (j, brandItem) => {
        /* here checking for each child for display as none. if any child 
         does not has display as a none then it set hideFlag as a false.*/
        if ($(brandItem).css('display') !== 'none') {
            hideFlag = false;
        }
    });
    if (hideFlag) {
        let $parent = $(bareList).parent().parent();
        $parent.hide();
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

By Looking at your function, what I assume as that filtering is done and you are able to see results in children. Let's take an example on basis of your search 'a', results in HTML are:

```
<div class='parent'>
  <div class='child1'> abcd </div>
  <div class='child2'> aef </div>
  <div class='child3' style='display: none'> bcd </div>
</div>
```

One is hidden, and other 2 are visible. Now code to check them is:

```
if($('.parent div').length > 0)
  $('.parent').show();
else
  $('.parent').hide();
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
$('input[type="text"]').keyup(function() {
  var that = this,
    $allListElements = $('ul.bare-list > li');

  var $matchingListElements = $allListElements.filter(function(i, li) {
    var listItemText = $(li).text().toUpperCase(),
      searchText = that.value.toUpperCase();
    return ~listItemText.indexOf(searchText);
  });

  $allListElements.hide();
  $matchingListElements.show();

 $('ul.bare-list').each(function() {
   if($(this).find('> li').length > 0)
      $(this).show();
   else
      $(this).hide();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="brand-container">
  <dl class="brands-letter letter-a" data-letter="letter-a">
    <dt>A</dt>
    <dd>
      <ul class="bare-list">
        <li class="brand-item">item 1</li>
        <li class="brand-item">item 2</li>
        <li class="brand-item">item 3</li>
      </ul>
    </dd>
  </dl>
  <dl class="brands-letter letter-b" data-letter="letter-b">
    <dt>B</dt>
    <dd>
      <ul class="bare-list">
        <li class="brand-item">item 1</li>
        <li class="brand-item">item 2</li>
        <li class="brand-item">item 3</li>
      </ul>
    </dd>
  </dl>
</div>
```